# Trigger AWS Event Rule based on Tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, events

I am trying to trigger AWS event rule based on successfully created snapshots containing certain tag.

This is the event rule I have:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ec2"],
  "detail-type": ["EBS Multi-Volume Snapshots Completion Status"],
  "detail": {
    "result": ["succeeded"],
    "event": ["createSnapshots"],
    "tagSpecificationSet": {
      "items": {
        "tags": {
          "Key": ["my-created-tag-key"],
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The snapshot gets created successfully and it contains the tag with both Key and Value being

```
my-created-tag-key
```

But the Event Rule does not pick it up, now if I remove the `tagSpecificationSet` it works, but I need to isolate it on the tag level, so not all successful snapshots trigger the Target.

To be honest, I have no idea what is wrong.

EDIT: Clarifying tag

The snapshot is tagged as per following:

```
Key: my-created-tag-key
Value: my-created-tag-key
```

Both Key and Value are the same.

Comment: Is the key of the tag actually `Key` ?

Comment: Nono, it's not, the value of the `Key` is `my-created-tag-key`

Comment: Try `key` instead of `Key`

Comment: Does EBS also emit tag details in JSON for a successful `createSnapshots` event?

Comment: In the console you get `Key` and `Value` but when you want to access these programmatically, its's always lower class( `key/value`). You can confirm it in cloudtrail after creating a snapshot manually.

Comment: I tried lower key but it does not work. Checking the cloudwatch, I noticed that when the followup target runs, it does not load the tags of the snapshot.